# Compute average for numbers from a to b using repetition

Tags: algorithm, loops, integer, average, flowchart

I am new to programming and i am currently learning algorithms and flowcharts.

I know how to write an algorithm for finding the inclusive sum between two integers with incrementation, but how can you calculate the average between two integers (input by user).

So  for example, if you have input a= 3 and b=6, the algorithm should increment a until a<=b and output avg=(3+4+5+6)/**4**.

But how do you write the division number / how would the program know with what number to divide the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get numbers `a` and `b` from user.
2. If `a > b`, swap them.
3. Create a counter, `c`, and initialise it to zero.
4. Create a sum variable, `s`, and initialise that to zero.
5. Loop from `a` to `b`, counting the number of loop iterations while summing up the integers that you loop through. This means adding 1 to `c` and adding the integer that you're currently at to `s`, in each iteration.
6. Output the sum `s` divided by the counter `c`.

Comment: I don't really know how to switch. And what happens when a=b?

Comment: @Paul If `a == b`, then the loop would execute once (if you write it correctly), and the sum would be `a` and the count would be one.  To swap the variables, set a temporary variable to `a`, set `a` to `b`, and then set `b` to the temporary variable.  In C: `t = a; a = b; b = t;`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you can just do the sum and then divide by (b-a+1)
So for your example you have: (3+4+5+6)/(6-3+1) = 18/4